# How to render array entries in JSX using map() function with conditional wrapping

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx, map-function

I have an array of objects in JavaScript and I want to loop through these objects and return some JSX with bootstrap classes in it such that each row always gets 2 columns displayed inside it.

```
options: [
  {
    "letter":"A",
    "text": "14 March 1879"
  },
  {
    "letter":"B",
    "text": "14 March 1897"
  },
  {
    "letter":"C",
    "text": "24 May 1879"
  },
  {
    "letter":"D",
    "text": "24 June 1879"
  }
]
```

In my experience with other languages and template engines, it is pretty simple: You just create an opening and a closing `div` tag with a class of `row` and then using your template engine, you loop through and render each object until when the counter of your loop is `2`, you dynamically end that role and start a new one.

Something like this:

```
<div class="row">
    for (var i in options) {
      if(i%2 === 0) {
        <!-- render object ... -->
        </div><!-- then end this row -->
        <div class="row"><!-- start new row -->
      } else {
        <!-- render object -->
      }
    }
</div>
```

I tried this method inside my map function and it was giving a syntax error because the value returned in the case where the condition passes is not valid JSX.

Thanks for any help.

Edit:

In the End, what I want to achieve is this:

If the array of objects contains 2 objects, I should be able to dynamically display it like this:

```
 <div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-6">
    <div class="option correct-option">
      A <!-- that is, option.letter -->
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-6">
    <div class="option wrong-option">
      B <!-- that is, option.letter -->
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

if the array contains 3 objects, I want to achieve this:

```
 <div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-6">
    <div class="option correct-option">
      A <!-- that is, option.letter -->
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-6">
    <div class="option wrong-option">
      B <!-- that is, option.letter -->
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-6">
    <div class="option correct-option">
      C <!-- that is, option.letter -->
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Post the HTML you want to achieve

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a regular for loop increasing `i` with 2 every loop, and check if the second option is set to take care of an array of uneven length:

**Example**

```
function App() {
  const content = [];

  for (let i = 0; i < options.length; i += 2) {
    content.push(
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6">
          <div class="option correct-option">{options[i].text}</div>
        </div>
        {options[i + 1] && (
          <div class="col-md-6">
            <div class="option correct-option">{options[i + 1].text}</div>
          </div>
        )}
      </div>
    );
  }

  return <div>{content}</div>;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

How about something like this?

```
{options.map((option, i) => (
    i % 2 === 0 ? null : ( // skip every 2nd row
      <div class="row">
        A: {option}
        B: {i < options.length ? options[i + 1] : null}
      </div>
    )
)}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It worked but the very first element of the returned array is null. I'm not sure why but I haven't yet figured it out

Answer (score 0):

HTML:

[image]

Result:

[image]

Validations:
Works with:
Array.length = 0
&
Array.length = n
You want 3 Cols?... define a const instead magic number "2"....

Code:

```
const options = [
  {
    "letter":"A",
    "text": "14 March 1879"
  },
  {
    "letter":"B",
    "text": "14 March 1897"
  },
  {
    "letter":"C",
    "text": "24 May 1879"
  },
];
return (
  <>
    {
      Array.from(Array(Math.round(options.length / 2)).keys()).map((number, index) => {
        return (
          <div className="row">
            {
                options.slice(index * 2, (index * 2) + 2).map(option=>{
                  return (
                    <div className="col-md-6">
                      <div className={`option ${option.true ? 'correct-option' : 'wrong-option'}`}>
                        {option.letter}-{option.text}
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  );
                })
              }
          </div>
        );
      })
    }
  </>
);
```